# How to set path of corpus in jajatr library

Tags: java

I have a text file ,i want to perform Automatic Term Recognition by using jajatr library. How can i set path of my file in this library. This library will process the text file and generate output file which will contain results.

I have downloaded this library from url provided below

< https://code.google.com/p/jajatr/downloads/list >

**I have studied and found this thing helpful**

After unzip the download folder . Traverse to the folder provided below

**jajatr\jajatr\src\jatr\src**

A Property File will be found named as **jatr**

Now set the text file path in the file named as **jatr**.

One of the statement in this file is :

**jatr.system.refcorpus=/mnt/minerva1/nlp/corpora/monolingual/english/gigaword/gw.lemmas.unigram_counts**

I think so that i have to set corpus path in this **jatr.properties** file
But I don't know how to set path of my corpus.

After running TestCValue.java class

### Output

**Usage: java TestTfIdf [path_to_corpus]**

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change `jatr.properties` file inside the `src` directory of the jar file. You can rather supply the property you are interested to customize when you run the jar through the command line, something like:

```
java -jar jajatr.jar -Djatr.system.refcorpus=%YOUR-PATH%
```

Comment: I do not require to set the path from command line. This properties file was added in my project and i need to set the path of corpus only inside this file.

Comment: Put in your properties file the part after the "D"